# SQLite "Drop table" error message: "SQL logic error or missing database"

Tags: sqlite, exception, drop-table

I am running a SQLite database in memory and I am attempting to drop a table with the following command.

```
DROP TABLE 'testing' ;
```

But when I execute the SQL statement, I get this error

```
SQL logic error or missing database
```

Before I run the "Drop Table" query I check to make sure that the table exists in the database with this query. So I am pretty sure that the table exists and I have a connection to the database.

```
SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' and name='testing';
```

This database is loaded in to memory from a file database and after I attempt to drop this table the database is saved from memory to the file system. I can then use a third party SQLite utility to view the SQLite file and check to see if the "testing" exists, it does. Using the same 3rd party SQLite utility I am able to run the "Drop TABLE" SQL statement with out error.

I am able to create/update tables without any problems.

**My questions:**

- Is there a difference between a memory database and a file database in SQLite when dropping a table?
- Is there a way to disable the ability to drop a table in SQLite that I may have accentually turned on somehow?

*Edit:* It appears to have something to do with a locked table. Still investigating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem when using Sqlite with the xerial jbdc driver in the version 3.7.2. and JRE7
I first listed all the tables with the select command as follows:

```
SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table'
```

And then tried to delete a table like this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TableName
```

I was working on a database stored on the file system and so it seems not to effect the outcome.
I used the `IF EXISTS` command to avoid  listing all the table from the master table first, but I needed the complete table list anyway.

For me the solution was simply to change the order of the `SELECT` and `DROP`.

Answer (score 2):

You should not have quotes in your DROP TABLE command.  Use this instead:

```
DROP TABLE testing
```

Comment: Oops, there are not quotes in the real version. I added them to the question to make things clear but I guess it just made things more complicated. Edited the question and removed the quotes.